# Java Out of Memory Issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, out-of-memory

I create a java object to query data from database. After I get the results and process then I no longer need the object. I also do not set the object reference to null in my code. Will Garbage collector considers this object for clean up? If the Garbage Collector do not clean up will this scenario create any kind of memory leak in the system?

Comment: Close the connection and it will be fine.

Comment: If you're querying a databae, you're likely using JDBC, which means you MUST close all the resources (ResultSet, Statement,Connection) when you're done with them. Do uou ?

Comment: As a general rule, Java objects become eligible for garbage collection when no more hard references exist to the object.  If you hold a reference to the object, it will not be collected unless the reference is in another object that is eligible for collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We cannot tell with this much information.

If you have created a local variable, used it, and not done anything else with it, then it will be available for garbage collection as soon as it goes out of scope.  If it's a variable within a method, for instance, then once the method returns, its reference is no longer counted as active by the garbage collector.  (You could, of course, have another reference to the same object somewhere else).

If, on the other hand, you have an instance variable, then it will hold on to its object as long as that instance of that object is active.  And, of course, if you have stored the reference in a static variable, then it is likely to just stay around as long as the program runs.

Comment: Thank you. The above explanation make sense.